# performance type varchar(1) or smallint to store status Postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, varchar

I'll store a status from 0 to 7 and I want to know which is the better type field to store, considering performance and space on Postgres database: varchar(1) or smallint.

By the way, is there any difference to set a field varchar(1) or varchar(100), still talking about performance and space?

Comment: Are we talking about a table with one column and one row to store an  integer value in range [0,7]?

Comment: If you're worried about the storage space impact of a single character, you may have time travelled from the 1960s.

Comment: @NevilleK - we worried about this kind of thing in the 1970's too... :-)

Comment: isn't it a valid concern, when you are talking about several billions of rows?@NevilleKuyt @BobJarvis

Comment: Let's say you have several billion rows and a `CHAR(1)` field. In this scenario the space-cost of that field is several gigabytes. Now, what's the dollar-cost of that? Google says that one terabyte disk drives cost about $45 these days. Given that, three gigabytes of space costs about 13.5 cents. So your question boils down to, "Is this status field worth 13.5 cents?" A `smallint` version of this field will occupy 2 bytes, so the cost is double - 27 cents. Best of luck.

Comment: I mean, let's say you have 120 billion rows. `smallint` takes 2 bytes you have to write to disk. `integer` takes 4 bytes. The difference is then 240 billion bytes. So, around 223 Gigabytes. Assuming an optimistic write performance of a single SSD drive, that would take more than 7 minutes. It seems to me quite a lot of time and space to worry about. Of course if you are talking about a thousand rows it is not so important to worry about data types. But I think it is good practice to ask yourself such questions and worry about the choice of data types and the impact on your use cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer @BobJarvis, ...., I was explaining my thinking while you quickly replied

Comment: Let's say that column also participates in 20 indexes (a pretty extreme case, but not unrealistic). Now you multiply multiple extra bytes per row 20 times, and that's not only cost of the storage, it also affects your RAM cache efficiency, which is more important (and significantly more expensive) resource. A bit too much to remove cognitive load on developers, that problem can be solved trivially on application side.

Comment: you mean `CHAR(1)`? I can't think of a single situation where `VARCHAR(1)` makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Bob Jarvis that this is really premature optimisation, I'll try to focus on the question as asked.

You're neglecting the most important choices. Your choices include:

- `smallint`
- `enum`
- `"char"`
- `character` and `character varying`

You could use an enumerated type. This is only really OK so long as you expect never to remove valid values, since PostgreSQL currently doesn't support deleting values from enum types.

Alternately, you could use the `"char"` data type. Yes, the quotes matter. It's a single character, like the C data type `char`. Without quotes `char` turns into `character(1)` at parse time.

`varchar` and `character` aren't really ideal for this because they're variable-width types with header overheads etc.

> By the way, is there any difference to set a field `varchar(1)` or `varchar(100)`, still talking about performance and space?

No. This is answered (many times) in other questions.

Comment: Going to necro this because Google hits puts it at the top.  Docs say "The type "char" (note the quotes) is different from char(1) in that it only uses one byte of storage. It is internally used in the system catalogs as a simplistic enumeration type."  The term "internal" gives me pause in that it may not be intended for external use?

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion you're fighting the wrong battle. You're worried about the performance impact of storing an integer instead of a single character field, which in my opinion is short-sighted thinking. The actual impact on performance of an integer vs. a single character is trivial, and I doubt this can be measured meaningfully. In my experience it's more important to reduce the cognitive loading on the developers and users of the system, and thus it's better to use character fields which are long enough to contain a reasonable description of the status instead of numeric values or single character abbreviations. Not having to remember what 1, 2, 'A', or 'X' mean is very helpful. Instead of these abbreviated values I suggest using easy-to-understand values such as  'READY', 'ACTIVE', 'PROCESSED', 'CANCELLED', etc.

As to the second part of the question - not really. There might be some trivial amount of time to move the longer string, but it's trivial unless you're talking about millions of values.

Best of luck.

Comment: You don't need to store a billion rows of "READY" "ACTIVE" etc to prevent users from having to translate single character codes.  That's what relations are for. Normalizing the db can have great benefits especially with large datasets.