# Is it worthwhile to split and store dates into yyyy, mm, dd, dow for future GROUP BY aggregates?

Tags: performance, postgresql, date

I will have partitioned tables of on the order of 20M rows on a shared server with a lot of disk space but limited RAM: <8GB. These tables essentially contain a timestamp, an ID, and a numeric performance indicator and I will be aggregating them to 15 minute bins, so the new table would be:

```
dt DATE NOT NULL,
id char(9) NOT NULL,
bintime int NOT NULL,
avg_score numeric(5,2) NOT NULL
```

My predecessor had split the `date` into different numeric components, presumably to optimize for different future aggregation queries so having a table with:

```
id char(9) NOT NULL,
yyyy smallint NOT NULL,
mm smallint NOT NULL,
dd smallint NOT NULL,
dow smallint NOT NULL,
bintime int NOT NULL,
avg_score numeric(5,2) NOT NULL
```

**I am wondering if it is worthwhile/beneficial to do this. Again, space is not an issue, but RAM is.**

From my research, I could even have each grouping column (yyyy,mm,etc.) be an [enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147700/4047679). And I've seen someone ask on the PostgreSQL list about [a similar question](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTi%3D14-tJAZO8QVf8ThHmmkcr_VqBFw%40mail.gmail.com), but this was storing dates as ints for ordering, not grouping. The answer they got was

> Keep in mind what Michael A. Jackson (among others) had to say on
>   this:
>   "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it.
>   The Second
>   Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."
>   For one thing, adding an extra column to your data would mean more
>   data you need to cram in the cache as you query, so even if the *raw*
>   integer versus date ordering is faster, the "optimization" could still
>   be a net loss due to the fatter tuples. If you're willing to live with
>   *only* integer-based dates, that could help, but that seems
>   exceptionally painful and not worth considering unless you run into
>   trouble.

Comment: Why don't you do both and test which one is faster?

Comment: The four fields are not orthogonal (Dow is dependent on the other three), so you introduce another level of required validation ...

Comment: @Grimxn, I get the orthogonal part, but don't quite follow the "extra" validation piece. Question should maybe explain that this is all static data.

Comment: Alas some of this can be very subjective based on the queries actually being performed.  It does feel wrong to split in this way.  **Maybe** If you were looking for every record on a Monday and DOW was indexed, but even then you could create a functional index on `extract(dow from foo)`

Comment: Depending on how data can be entered / created you have introduced the possibility of invalid data. What would you do with an entry that read 2016/8/16/7? - the fields are all valid, but they don't match up. No one knowingly creates bugs, but data has a tendency to develop a life of its own through time...

Comment: @PhilipCouling good point about functional indices.
Grimxn: data will be bulkloaded and then static, so this shouldn't be an issue, but thanks for raising that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary results of my investigation.

#### Table creation

Without ymd:
Time **35:34 minutes** (from Python script)
Table size: **538 MB**
With ymd:
Time **59:17 minutes to 4:30:14 hrs** (from pgadmin query window)
Table size: **562 MB**

#### Aggregation to month-weekday

Without ymd: **1:42**
With ymd: **1:36**

I have yet to test with indexes.

### Preliminary conclusions:

Marginal increase in aggregation query performance not worth substantial creation query time. Table size difference is negligible (surprisingly). Feel free to add more suggestions for testing.